# Using default SSL certificate in Istio ingress gateway in GKE

Tags: ssl, google-kubernetes-engine, istio

We are using GKE with managed Istio. We need to configure HTTPS ingress access to a list of HTTP services.

With the default Istio installation on GKE, I do see following two directories in the ingressgateway pod:

```
ingressgateway-ca-certs
ingressgateway-certs
```

But I am unable to see the certificate and the key files in there. 
I am not sure if I am missing anything.

I also see the certificate when I run following:

```
kubectl get secret istio-ca-secret --namespace istio-system -o yaml
```

Do we have to explicitly install new certificates to enable HTTPS ingress or is there a way to use the one created by Istio/GKE by default?

Comment: I am using istio-system in my self hosted kubernetes production, created by kops. 
I had to load my ssl cert files in istio-ingressgateway-certs which belongs to my domain name. I am sure GKE ll also work same. please look into it 
https://istio.io/docs/tasks/traffic-management/ingress/ingress-certmgr/

Comment: The above link seems to work when using Kubernetes Ingress, I should have been more clear in my question. 
I need to use Istio Gateway for traffic management and I am using GKE managed Istio. I just found that it's possible to configure a custom ingress gateway using cert manager: https://istio.io/blog/2019/custom-ingress-gateway/. However, I am not sure I would be able to do it on GKE managed Istio. I will try this out and post my findings here.

Comment: I did not use GKE managed Istio yet.

Answer (score 0):

You can set a custom SSL certificate a custom Istio Ingress Gateway:

https://istio.io/blog/2019/custom-ingress-gateway

For a GKE managed Istio the changes could be reverted back to the default values during the automatic upgrade. But you can create a new ingress gateway:

https://cloud.google.com/istio/docs/istio-on-gke/installing#adding_gateways